# f:setPropertyActionListener is not calling target in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, actionlistener

I am working on popup to pass some values but looks like the target is not triggering.

This is the button :

```
    <p:column headerText="View" style="text-align: center;" width="80">

                <p:commandButton update=":dialogueForm:uploadHistory" value="View"
                    oncomplete="PF('historyDialog').show()" icon="ui-icon-search"
                    title="View">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{as}"
                        target="#{remoteDeployment.selectedTerminalRemoteDeploymentSettings}" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
```

This is the dialogue box :

```
<p:dialog id="dlg" header="History" widgetVar="historyDialog"
            showEffect="explode">
            <h:form id="dialogueForm">
                <p:outputPanel id="uploadHistory" style="text-align:center;">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2"
                        rendered="#{not empty remoteDeployment.selectedTerminalRemoteDeploymentSettings}"
                        columnClasses="label,value">

                        <h:outputText value="Branch Name:" />
                        <p:inputText
                            value="#{remoteDeployment.selectedTerminalRemoteDeploymentSettings.terminalId}" />
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```

selectedTerminalRemoteDeploymentSettings is always empty. 
please help.

Comment: Hi, [mcve] please. Could be too many things wrong and guessing etc.  would take to much time. And how is the dialog related?

Comment: Verify if the set value is working when you are clicking in the button.

Comment: And where is your managedBean and complementary code?